# Automated tests for audio on iOS

Tags: ios, audio, integration-testing, e2e-testing, earlgrey

I am setting up automated (e2e) tests (using [Detox](https://github.com/wix/detox)) for an iOS app. Part of the app records and processes audio input. In order to fully test the app I need to be able to simulate audio input. Ideally by playing back a specific audio file. But it could be any audio at this stage. I am trying to work out if and how I might be able to achieve this. Detox uses [EarlGrey](http://google.github.io/EarlGrey/index.html)  which supports most UI interactions, but not audio.

One possibility is to include some kind of special "mock" mode which detects when its being run in a test, and instead of recording input from the microphone, stream it from a file. But I'd rather not have to tinker with the application code like this if possible.

Comment: Hey Adam, we can continue this conversation on the Github Issue. Thanks a lot for filing it.

https://github.com/google/EarlGrey/issues/553

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detox 5.5.0 supports [additional launch arguments](https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.DeviceObjectAPI.md#6-additional-launch-arguments)

```
await device.launchApp({launchArgs: {arg1: 1, arg2: "2"}});
```

Which can then be accessed in your app:

```
[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments][@"arg1"]
[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments][@"arg2"]
```